# How do I change a content part of my website by changing the url keeping the menus static and already running?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, reactjs

I really need a good help I am looking for and nothing.
I am doing a project with music in the browser and / or in an application, that is, I need to work with html / php / js / css, if I do it on a website I easily step into an application, I assume, with react for example, with a load window.
that is, I wanted a framework, or anything else that was possible, to have a menu always active, and when clicking on the menus, change the content of the page in the middle, which continues with the menu without being changed, the music playing and changing up url.
such as spotify, it has a menu at the bottom and side that never changes but the middle content changes and the url too
I'm not finding any way to do this well ... if someone managed to help me, I would be very grateful

Comment: Try to research on SPA (single page application), there are good JS framework you can use for that. But, your question is not well formatted, please also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reactrouter might be what u are looking for. It is good library for react apps that need to switch between different views depending on URL. They have good documentation on their website and I recommend that you look them up.

Comment: thank you i will take a look, the demo video i saw seems to be exactly that, but it will be complicated to learn i think ... because i have to do an 80 hour project in class ...